# Google input tool not working on SSL certified website

Tags: html, google-input-tools

I am having a `textarea` element and I am using the Google input tool in that and it's working fine in localhost. When I am using same code on an HTTPS domain it's not working.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://suryaprakashanmandir.com/transliteration.I.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("elements", "1", {
    packages: "transliteration"
  });

  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
      sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
      destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
      shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
      transliterationEnabled: true
    };
    var control =
      new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

    control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
<textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
```

The code shows:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://suryaprakashanmandir.com/something.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text=hello&ime=transliteration_en_hi&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv&cb=_callbacks_._0k5me1vjh'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to site setting and allow Insecure content

[image]

[image]

Comment: but we can't say it to every user to do this